# How do I change my DNS address to something other than 8.8.8.8?

Tags: router, dns

My DNS address seem to be set to 8.8.8.8 (primary) and 8.8.4.4 (secondary). These are Google DNS addresses, right? How can I change this so that I get the DNS address from my ISP? I can't change this in Windows because the computer is connected to a D-Link router, and I can't find any option to change this in the router.

Comment: Why is it set to Google DNS?... I don't get it. I don't recall doing this. Where do I find the option for this in the router? I would like to get the DNS from my ISP.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with Google's DNS? I prefer it greatly over my ISP's

Comment: Were your DNS settings assigned through DHCP?

Comment: @SimonSheehan: There are always privacy concerns when using a Google service.

Comment: @SimonSheehan I don't think there is anything wrong with the Google DNS but I just find it strange that it would be set to Google DNS and not my ISPs DNS. I want to check it out and see what's going on there.

Comment: @Sammy your ISP might be cheaping out and using google instead ;)

Comment: Why don't you just change it on your PC instead of automatically configuration?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Can I change it on the PC? Even though the PC is connected to the router? How?...

Comment: Guys all I see when I enter the web ui is how to enable dynamic DNS. I go to Tools, then "dynamic DNS", and then check "Enable Dynamic DNS". But this is not it, right?...

Comment: In Windows, you go to the Control Panel and you can tell DNS to not be automatically configured and put in your own DNS information.

Comment: @CodeMonkey From the "Properties for Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" dialog? By setting my own DNS IP in here, will this override the DNS set in my router?...

Comment: Nope, it will only affect your PC.

Comment: @CodeMonkey That's what I meant. And yes, you were right about that.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to change the DNS is because my ISPs DNS seem to be quicker than Google. I was probably the one who changed the router to Google DNS when I had trouble once with DNS responsiveness with a previous ISP. Pinging 8.8.8.8 50 times gives me 22 ms low, 1831 ms high, 59 ms avarage. I get similar results for 8.8.4.4. When pinging one of my ISPs DNS servers I get 12 ms low, 2689 ms high, 66 ms avarage. The second DNS from my ISP gave me 16 ms low, 18 ms high and 16 ms avarage. This is the one I use now I can definitely see a change in performance when I browse the web.

Comment: In short: that's about two times faster, more responsive web browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your router settings, and modify it there. Your router's IP is likely 192.168.0.1

Once you get there, login using your d-link router's credentials, and then modify your DNS settings under the header "DNS." You may need to ask your ISP which DNS servers you should be using.

Comment: I go to 192.168.0.1 log in and go to Setup, Netwrok Settings, and there is no option for it. But when I go to Status I see these two IP numbers on the WAN side.

Comment: @Sammy What kind of modem do you have? Is it one of those funky router/modem combo ones?

Comment: There is no modem in the setup. No, it's a router only model. I tagged the question as DIR-825.

Comment: What ISP do you use? It's possible (not likely) they are using google dns for some reason. Also, I can't get to the dlink site right now, but I believe you need to look under the 'advanced' network menu for the DHCP options.

Comment: @jhayes I have these categories under Advanced: virtual server, port forwarding, application rules, qos engine, network filter, access control, website filter, inbound filter, firewall settings, routing, advanced wireless, wi-fi protected setup, advanced network, guest zone, ipv6. None of these mention anything about DNS. Any idea where it might be?

Comment: @jhayes My ISP is AllTele. Link: http://www.netnod.se/alltele-as44581-upgraded-10-gbps-gothenburg

Comment: Finally! I found it by going to 192.168.0.1 then Setup, then Internet and then the button Manual Internet Connection Setup.