# Computer blocking websites?

Tags: windows, website

### The problem

I've got my website up again, however I'm now unable to connect to it. I was able to connect for a short time, but now again I can't. It says that the website is too slow to answer.

### I have tried:

- Asking other people to access my site, they can. www.isup.com says it's up too.
- Contacting my webhost, they said that my IP was not blocked
- Accessing it from a different browser
- Disabling my firewall and anti-virus
- Changing my DNS server (to Google's `8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4`)
- `ipconfig /flushdns`

### Some details:

- `ping` times out every time
- I can access other websites hosted on the same webhost
- I've hosted a site on the same domain before, but with a diffrent hosting company

So it must be my PC. How can I see if any application or something like that is blocking access to the site?

Comment: What error messages are you seeing, if any? What browser are you using? Have you tried using a different web browser or doing a [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility))? Do you have an anti-virus program enabled? Have you tried disabling it? Your question could have a variety of different answers, please add more details.

Comment: traceroute or pathping would be useful here too

Comment: @Alex , it's in Danish but it says that the server was too slow to answer. No anti-virus, no firewall, other browsers doesn't work and ping result timed out everytime.

Comment: @Steffen looks like a DNS issue, try [changing you DNS server](http://superuser.com/a/433362/202306) to Google's `8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4` or something else if you already use theirs. Make sure your browser/system use it as well.

Comment: @Alex I've now configured Windows and my router to use Google's DNS which did not work.

Comment: Is it the only website with this issue? Try accessing other websites hosted in that company from your computer, it could be an issue with your ISP and that iprange. I edited your question adding the info you provided in the comments and upvoted it so it gets more attention, I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: @Alex I'm able to connect to other websites of the host just fine. I've hosted a site on the same domain before, but with a diffrent hosting company. It might be that?

Comment: @Steffen I guess it could. Try issuing `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command prompt. It will clear the DNS cache on your computer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Alex it didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things you can try is to capture traffic with a packet capture software, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). With wireshark you will see all traffic going in and out of your system. You may also want to capture traffic elsewhere on your network so you can see what is happening off of your system, but on your network (note the other system must be connected by a hub, not a switch or router without more complex configs).

Using wireshark you should be able to see your requests and your responses. If you don't see responses, this may mean its being blocked somewhere. To troubleshoot further would depend upon the results from these tests.

You may also want to try a live Linux CD with wireshark. It might be something on your local system, this would allow you to test with a different platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check the entries in `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`